# Type 'string | ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: javascript, typescript, arraybuffer

TypeScript error for reading string from FileReader

Simple code to read file contents:

```
const reader: FileReader = new FileReader();
       reader.readAsText(file);
       reader.onload = (e) => {
          const csv: string = reader.result; -> getting TS error on this line
}
```

TypeScript error I get:

```
Type 'string | ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  Type 'ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Comment: cast the `reader.result` to `string`.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The error message says it all.

You declare a `string` type of `csv` variable.
You then assign `string | ArrayBuffer` type (of `reader.result`) to the `string` type, you just assigned. You cannot. You only can assign `string` to `string`.

So, if you 100% sure that `reader.result` contains `string` you could assert this:

```
const csv: string = reader.result as string;
```

However if you are not sure, do this:

```
const csv: string | ArrayBuffer = reader.result;
// or simply:
const csv = reader.result; // `string | ArrayBuffer` type is inferred for you
```

Then you typically should have some check like:

```
if (typeof csv === 'string') {/*use csv*/}
else {/* use csv.toString() */}
```

Comment: You could also just do `toString` anyway like `const csv = reader.result.toString()` It takes care of everything, silencing the type error, and converting to string anyway.

Answer (score 5):

This will always output a string regardless if `csv` is a `string` or an `ArrayBuffer`.

```js
const csv: string = typeof csv === 'string' ? csv : Buffer.from(csv).toString()
```